# TypeScript conditional return type for generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function which makes it easy to infer the structure of the `run` method inside the task definition below. Is it possible to create a conditional return value so that `inferTest1` has the type `{ skipped: boolean; result: number }` and `inferTest2` receives the type `{ skipped: boolean }` without a result property?

```js
interface TaskDefinition<T> {
  run: () => { skipped: boolean } | { skipped: boolean; result: T };
}

function createTask<T>(
  task: TaskDefinition<T>
): { skipped: boolean; result: T } | { skipped: boolean } {
  const taskResult = task.run();
  if ("result" in taskResult) {
    return {
      skipped: taskResult.skipped,
      result: taskResult.result,
    };
  }
  return {
    skipped: taskResult.skipped,
  };
}

const inferTest1 = createTask({
  run: () => ({
    skipped: false,
    result: 251,
  }),
});

const inferTest2 = createTask({
  run: () => ({
    skipped: false,
  }),
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest solution here would be to use overloads:

```
interface TaskDefinition<T> {
  run: () => { skipped: boolean } | { skipped: boolean; result: T };
}

function createTask<T>(task: { run: () => { skipped: boolean; result: T } }): { skipped: boolean; result: T }
function createTask(task: { run: () => { skipped: boolean } }): { skipped: boolean }
function createTask<T>(task: TaskDefinition<T>): { skipped: boolean; result: T } | { skipped: boolean } {
  const taskResult = task.run();
  if ("result" in taskResult) {
    return {
      skipped: taskResult.skipped,
      result: taskResult.result,
    };
  }
  return {
    skipped: taskResult.skipped,
  };
}

const inferTest1 = createTask({
  run: () => ({
    skipped: false,
    result: 251,
  }),
});
inferTest1.result

const inferTest2 = createTask({
  run: () => ({
    skipped: false,
  }),
});
inferTest2.result // err
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-V4polcpM9sdvom-r4gZAwdDYHdEZqyAA9HXkNAoEA)

You could also use conditional types, but I think that is overkill here.

Another solution would be to infer the result of run itself, although that might interfere with other things you are doing in the function:

```
function createTask<T extends { skipped: boolean } | { skipped: boolean; result: T }>(task: { run: () => T }): T {
    const taskResult = task.run();
    // Only spreading or type assertions will work to satisfy T, also narrowing is now borken
    return {
        ...taskResult
    };
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCpwM4GsAiEajBjAD2IAPKgHzIDeAsAFDIvJQCuIAXMgBQCUyALw1aybMAAOkiABMeAIxIkANhDghkAX2QAfOuKxSZ85EtXqQAbjYQM7FWB6ptVplqZMYnBMTLIEKHVIdGxKZAgAD0gQWQwDCWk5RWU1DW09BKMk03M061t7R2dtKl4wTCweMQ5uPkERNG1+EoZmVgQyDDBkCuwAJTsHHqFeyoA6WoE3dpYAejnkAHkQFQBPcUkguFlQAHNkEihetZlkTAxoPxB4gHdgFRVkW6OsABpzlQwSZBA4KBI9xAB2A8RAgLMrwgICYrFsYHYUE0bThcPG6L6WEGRTAsNYWhmHkYTE6Nx6oBg0FQdjAAEZhAFtiFKrwUaxajwBMIaKy8ajDMZksh4F8IG8+aigjieAAmACstPFs2aSq0-BmFKpNNpkyGjk8jFJ3WQmqg1O6MoZgWCEFCWF5yo59W5fDZ-MSJh4IsuSrhatV6qYpvNYBlupxyAWESgUCAA)

Comment: Awesome, thanks your first suggestion with overloads works well for me!